# Replace all file keys with new values using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

What's the best way to find and replace the values of all keys in a file without precising the keys ?

Example :

```
originalFile.txt  ------------------------------------>  newFile.txt              
key1=a                                                   key1=$key1
key2=b                                                   key2=$key2
key3=c                                                   key3=$key3
```

I came up with this but I'm not able to do it dynamically for any new added key  :

```
sed '/^key1/s/=.*$/= $key1/' newFile.txt
```

Comment: I updated the description, the new value of the key in a env variable

Comment: $key1 etc are env variables, so I can access them from bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -vFS="=" -v OFS="=" '$2="$"$1' originalFile.txt
```

Using `sed`: using back referencing capture the left of `=` in `\1` and right of `=` in `\2`:

```
sed -r 's/(^[^=]+)*=(.*)/\1=$\1/g' originalFile.txt
key1=$key1
key2=$key2
key3=$key3
```

Comment: The script can't evaluate the env variable $key1. How can we do that ?

Comment: how are you using `key1` ?

Comment: A couple of points: First, the `g` flag is superfluous since the regexp is anchored by the `^`. Second, the second group is also unnecessary since is not referenced. Also, if the OP wants the variable instantiated, by adding the `e` flag to the RHS of the substitution, they will be evaluated, however the original variables must be exported first or the saved file could be sourced.

Comment: rather than priting key1=$key1, I want to print the eval of $key1 => key1=key1value

Comment: @user3574857 can you post another question with updated problem statement and  examplet

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sed -re 's/^(key[[:digit:]]+)=.*$/\1=\$\1/' originalFile.txt
```

It works because (since the `-r` options is used) a pair of parentheses *captures* its match. In the substitution pattern, the `\1` reproduces the text matched.

Comment: You can amend the pattern to suit. The idea of @PS. should work.

Answer (score 0):

this script extract the password from env and include it in the new file:

```
while read line; do
    password=$(echo $line | sed "s/\(.*\)=.*/\1/g")
    newpassword="$(printenv $password)"
    if [ -n "$newpassword" ]; then
       echo "$password=$newpassword"
    else
       echo $line
    fi 
done <originalFile.txt >newFile.txt
```